# Java instantiate C++ class from DLL

Tags: java, c++, dll

I wrote a set of C++ classes and created a DLL that exports one of these C++ classes. I need to instantiate the exported C++ class in a Java class. Is that possible?

I searched the web for a possible solution, but all I have found where solutions using JNA or JNI that import C++ **functions** only.

Comment: There are only native **methods** in Java.

Comment: There is no chance of instantiating C++ classes?

Comment: Not directly. Maybe you can write a wrapper class.

Comment: My class holds some state information (among which pointers to other C++ classes are stored) that is needed as long as the object lives. So each method that I may access from Java refers to that information.

Comment: Ok, but, what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can instantiate a C++ class from Java.

One way is with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which can generate Java wrappers for C++ classes.

For example, given a C++ class like this:

```
class MyClass { 
public:
     MyClass();
     int myMethod( int arg );
}
```

SWIG allows you to write Java code like this:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
int val = myClass.myMethod( 42 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. SWIG works like a charm! BTW: I am not using Visual Studio and, thus, I had to write my own Makefile to compile my sources and generate the appropriate SWIG files. I used the Makefile from http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#nmake and adjusted it to my needs.

Comment: You're welcome. Congratulations on learning SWIG and getting it to work with your C++ API in under a day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate a C++ class from Java, you'll have to write a little glue code (in C++) that instantiates the desired object. Further, you'll need a Java class that corresponds to the C++ class, and you need to have the glue code convert the C++ object into an object of the Java class aforementioned, and keeps them together (i.e., changes to the C++ object should reflect to the Java object, and the other way around).

[This tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) seems to have some pointers how you could do that. Specifically, it tells you how to instantiate a Java object, which is what you will need for the above approach.